# MongoDB vs TokuMX - Why shouldnt TokuMX be used by default instead of MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, tokumx

TokuMX is a opensource drop-in replacement for MongoDB. It has features like transactions,compression etc which give it a upper hand compared to MongoDB.. Then why isnt TokuMX the default choice ahead of MongoDB?? Has anyone here used TokuMX in production?

Answer (score 5):

We were evaluating TokuMX some months ago, and the main reason we rejected it was absence of new 2.6 features (it was based on 2.4 mongo engine that time).
Additionally, we found that a real compression was pretty far from what is advertised (in our case, of course, your case may be closer to their ideal conditions), and almost no gain in performance. We decided that the game is not worth the candle.

Comment: Interesting, they claim to be a highly performant distro of MongoDB.Do you mean they have no roadmap?

Comment: (disclaimer, I'm an employee of Tokutek) The TokuMX roadmap is available at https://tokutek.atlassian.net/browse/MX/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:roadmap-panel. As for compression, TokuMX can only compress data that is compressible and will perform comparable to what you'd get by running a mongodump of your data through 7zip or gzip.

Answer (score 0):

I was drawn towards TokuMX since it gave better performance and had good compression of data but as I went deeper, I found that TokuMX doesn't support text Search and the Mongo engine is v2.4 which was very disappointing. Having said that TokuMX v2.1 seems to support Mongo engine v2.6 but has no mention of text search and the release date is uncertain.
Also Note that you get better insert and update performance in TokuMX due to fractal tree indexing but read speed is not much of a difference. Since My application was more to do with read it was pretty straight decision for me to drop TokuMX and move on with Mongo v2.6.
Make sure you consider all the points above while selecting TokuMX.